# non build files of eclipse project in git repository

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git

I have files that are associated with my Android project, that are not needed for the build. For example `.svg` files to generate icons, README file, `apk` files etc.

Since i would like these files to be part of my project's local git repository(and GitHub), where can i place them? If i place them inside the project folder, it shows up in the Project Explorer in Eclipse. I wonder if it then becomes part of the build and therefore the `apk`. Is there a convention for this?

Comment: Are these resources that are part of your application in some way?

Comment: @chrylis They are not part of the application in any way. I just use them during the development and publishing process.

Comment: Use them for what? Are they marketing materials or such?

Comment: @chrylis yes exactly

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like they aren't actually associated with the code itself. You'll need to tell more about how your project is structured; are you using a Maven-style directory layout with `src/main`, or something else?

Comment: i am not familiar with Maven. I just use the default directory structure created by Eclipse, probably by the ADT plugin. It has src, gen, res, bin, libs, proguard. My java code is in packages in src folder. My images and xml are in res folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing them in a subfolder in the project folder should work.

I have tested this by placing a subfolder `svg` with 19 `.svg` files totalling 100 kb in my project folder. The resulting `.apk` was the exact same size as before. So ADT's building process is intelligent enough to ignore miscellaneous folders.

Answer (score 0):

If there are files/directories that you do not want to push to the repository, you should use the .gitignore file.

Create a .gitgnore file in the root directory of the git project. This is what a typical .gitignore file looks like in case of android.

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_
# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex
# Java class files
*.class
# Generated files
bin/
gen/
# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/
# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties
# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/
# Log Files
*.log
```

You can add options similar to these as required. E.g *.svg if you want to ignore svg files.

For files that are already added to your git repo, you'll need to use the `git rm` command to remove them from being tracked.

e.g `git rm bin *.svg`

Then use git add and commit as usual. All files matching the criteria in the .gitgnore file will not be tracked in any future commits.

Comment: Wrong direction. He *does* want to add resources to git but have them excluded from the build artifact.